# Demo (FX) Coding Tutorials?

Tags: language-agnostic, demoscene

I'm looking for a few good tutorials to get me started in [demo coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demo_(computer_programming)). I have some background in CG but it's all rather theoretical.
There are many regular 3D programming tutorials, but I'm especially looking for some old school 2D stuff.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are some good demo coding examples in the demoscene magazine [Hugi](http://www.hugi.scene.org/main.php?page=hugi) issues.

Answer (score 15):

First of all join [pouet.net](http://pouet.net/). Here is a [list of all prods with source code](http://www.pouet.net/sourceprod.php).

Hang out on ircnet, on #ukscene, #pouet.net, #coders, #Breakpoint, #bitfellas, #macscene

Also [iq](http://iquilezles.org/prods/) has written a huge number of [tutorials](http://iquilezles.org/www/)

Comment: Source code alone rarely helps with getting started but the Inigo link is awesome. http://iquilezles.org/www/material/framework64k/framework64k.htm especially.

Answer (score 4):

Scene.org has a nice [collection](http://www.scene.org/dir.php?dir=%2Fresources%2Fcode/) of sources to old school effects and stuff. It's quite hard to browse through though.

Answer (score 1):

[The Art of Demomaking](http://www.flipcode.com/archives/articles.shtml) by Alex Chambard at good old flipcode.